# Adding custom text after portable USB drive letter

Tags: usb, external-hard-drive, usb-flash-drive, dvd, autorun

Kinda fancy question, but how can I add custom text after portable drive letter name?

My DVD has the following name pattern:

- `Label (DriveLetter:) CustomText`

But my other USB portable drive has:

- `Label (DriveLetter:)`

Studying the `autorun.inf` I discovered the `action` field, but modifying it doesn't work.

Does it matter that device type is DVD?
What software can I use to change this text?

[image]

Comment: Isn't that filesystem / volume label?

Answer (score 0):

#### How can I add custom text after portable drive letter name?

Use the `label` command in a `cmd` shell.

Example:

```
label G:examplelabel
```

To display existing labels use the `vol` command:

```
vol G:
```

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line | SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/)
- [Windows CMD Commands (categorized) - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/commands.html)
- [Label - Disk label - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/label.html)
- [Vol - volume label - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/vol.html)